# Question about ように

Tags: grammar

I'm confused in ように in the following sentence. Maybe it connects to 聞こえる or maybe means "in order to" ? I'm not sure about it here.

Some sort of translation:
"Conversations in this period of time means, that *they are* taking the opportunity to clear the gloom from exams studying, the fact that it sounds a bit unnatural maybe is my imagination."

> この時期の会話というのは、受験勉強の鬱屈【うっ・くつ】をここぞとばかりに晴らそうとするように、妙にキンキンと聞こえるのは気のせいだろうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a split apart [～ように聞こえる](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E8%81%9E%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B&ref=sa) (sounds like ~ / sounds as if ~).

聞こえる is modified twice, once by the clause ending in ように, and once again by 妙にキンキンと.

> この時期の会話というのは、受験勉強の鬱屈をここぞとばかりに晴らそうとするように、妙にキンキンと聞こえるのは気のせいだろうか。
>   The(se things called) conversations around this period, I wonder if it is my imagination that they sound unnaturally shrill, and **like/as if** they are an attempt to eagerly snatch at the opportunity to clear up the gloom of studying for exams.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning seems to be:

> About this period's conversation, its meaning is that, "I wonder whether hearing the 'kin kin' (piercing, metallic sound) exactly in the right moment, such that it cleared up my exam-studying gloom, was just imagination."

The するように is a device for expressing that the sound's effect was *such as to* clear up the gloom.

Comment: Potentially [useful link](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB).